# Filter and count entries for each hour, over the last 24hours from a specific date

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently aggregating some data. I already done aggregation where I would count entries per day, as you can see in the code below.

I've got no idea how to even start with this aggregation. 
I assume it would be something to do with my current date time, minus 24 hours and then get the count for each hour in the 24 hours.

```
Collection = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c125a185dea1b0252c895b2"),
    "time" : ISODate("2018-12-13T15:09:42.536Z"),
}


pipeline = [
        {"$unwind": "$time"},
        {"$group": {
            "_id": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$time","timezone": "Africa/Johannesburg"}},
            "count": {"$sum": 1},
        }},
        {"$sort": SON([("_id", -1)])}
    ]
```

This is the code for the daily aggregation.

Further help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the `time` field an array?

Comment: ISO Date in UTC time